# I need help about flatButton

Tags: flutter, flatbutton

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: FlatButton(
          color: (buttons == EQUAL_SIGN)
              ? Theme.of(context).primaryColor
              : Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),
          child: Text(
            buttons,
            style: TextStyle(
                color: (_colorTextButtons())
                    ? Colors.blueAccent
                    : (buttons == EQUAL_SIGN)
                        ? Theme.of(context).buttonColor
                        : Color(0xFF444444),
                fontSize: _fontSize() ? 18 : 20.0),
          ),
          onPressed: () => onTap(buttonText: buttons),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I try to replace with TextButton but nothing.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: TextButton(
          color: (buttons == EQUAL_SIGN)
              ? Theme.of(context).primaryColor
              : Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),
          child: Text(
            buttons,
            style: TextStyle(
                color: (_colorTextButtons())
                    ? Colors.blueAccent
                    : (buttons == EQUAL_SIGN)
                        ? Theme.of(context).buttonColor
                        : Color(0xFF444444),
                fontSize: _fontSize() ? 18 : 20.0),
          ),
          onPressed: () => onTap(buttonText: buttons),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I wonder if you need to expand on the problem - "but nothing" isn't a detailed fault report. Please also summarise the problem in the title - "need help" isn't a fault report either. Be specific.

Comment: Error messages are useful, if you are getting them. Stack traces are useful. Observations about what you expected and what you got are good too.

Answer (score 2):

We don't have any `FlatButton` on the current version of Flutter. You can use `TextButton`.

[image]

Find more about this [breaking-changes/buttons](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/buttons#context).

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `flatButton` into some other button like `textButton`; it is due to update of Flutter that made the `flatButton` can't be used anymore.

Here is the example of simple usage textButton:

```dart
 TextButton(
     style: TextButton.styleFrom(
        textStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
     ),
     onPressed: null,
        child: const Text('Disabled'),
     ),
```

Comment: Just a quick suggestion: "deprecated" means that something is not recommended. In software terms it is quite different to a feature being removed. Something that is missing now probably was deprecated in the past. The current status of an old feature would probably be called "removed".

Comment: using TextButton I get errors in colors and padding attributes